# Maven ear deployment through jboss

Tags: maven

We are mavenising our project which is having web modules,jar modules,ejb modules.I am able to build a ear module which is bundled with those ejb modules, web modules and some external jars in lib folder.here my problem is i have some internal jar modules to bundle in ear lib folder.When i do build from terminal i am able to build ear with all modules.But when i import ear alone(without importing my internal jar modules) and start deployment, the deployment is failed due to the missing internal jars from ear lib folder.but it is working fine when i import all internal jar modules also.

Is it required to import all modules Mavenised in my project? Cann't it by importing only ear module.